# No reaction to website login with Selenium

Tags: c#, php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I can login to the PHP website https://panel-support.oasgames.com/panel/ajaxrela/login manually, which will show a bird animation and on failed login show "Failed to login" on the website, whereas on successful login it will redirect to the main page. Login happens via POST, which returns JSON. But when I use the following executable snippet and login in the automated Chrome window (manually or using selenium commands), the bird animation shows but nothing else happens on failed or successful login. (Feel free to test that with bogus login data). Commented out commands are for logging in via selenium, here with bogus login data:

```
    private static IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://panel-support.oasgames.com/panel/ajaxrela/login");
        //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
        //wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy((By
            .Name("username"))));
        //driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys("foo");
        //driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("bar");
        //driver.FindElement(By.TagName("button")).Click();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        driver.Quit();
    }
```

Comment: What is it that you want to do? Your code only contains commands for logging in, then waiting a second before quitting the driver. When I try the login manually I first get a bird animation, then a modal with an error message when I fail to login. Is your problem that you cannot see/interact with this modal with the selenium driver?

Comment: I want to login and have omitted the code I do after logging in. I figured that the reason I can't see the modal on failed login with the selenium driver is probably the same problem as that nothing happens when submitting the correct login data using the selenium driver. That's why I formulated the problem this way, so that I don't have to make my login data public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector for username and password are incorrect. They should be `By.Name()`.

```
driver.FindElement(By.Name("username")).SendKeys("foo");
driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys("bar");
driver.FindElement(By.TagName("button")).Click();
```

Comment: It's true that the selectors were incorrect, but changing them to By.Name() doesn't help with the problem that the error message on failed login only shows when logging in manually, but not when logging in via the selenium driver. The fields are filled in in both cases.

Comment: @rubystallion Can you add `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);` before click the button?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That didn't change anything either, same when adding that command before every selenium command.

Comment: @rubystallion That's weird. It works fine on my machine. Can you check version of chromedriver, selenium, and Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the protocol (the beginning of the link string) to https and everything worked as expected. @Buaban's answer led me see that my Windows proxy settings were incorrect, but after changing the settings it worked in Edge and IE manually, but still not in Chrome. So I assume some Chrome security settings prevented me from logging in via selenium driver, although it's probably also because I'm accessing the page via VPN.

Comment: If @Buaban answer led you to some improvement, I think he deserves at least an upvote. Maybe you could even mark his answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a nudge there. Now I see the text when hovering over the accept mark also mentions "most helpful in finding your solution", correct.